# php mapping value to corresponding value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of all countries in the world. Below is a portion of that array (for the sake of the question):

```
array(  
    'AD' => 'Andorra',  
    'AE' => 'United Arab Emirates',  
    'AF' => 'Afghanistan',  
    'AG' => 'Antigua and Barbuda',  
    'AI' => 'Anguilla',  
    'AL' => 'Albania',  
    'AM' => 'Armenia',  
    'AN' => 'Netherlands Antilles',  
    ...
);
```

In the database I store the value such as AD, AE, etc. When i want to display which country the user is from, I will need to map the AD to Andorra for example so that my function returns Andorra instead of AD. How can I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: `return $countries_array['AD'];`

Answer (score 0):

> it is very simple

```
$query = "SELECT countryname,countryalias FROM country"
$result = mysql_query($query);
$CountryArray = array()
while($row = mysql_fetch_object()){
   $CountryArray[$row->countryalias ] = $row->countryname;
}
var_dump($CountryArray);
```